# How to make 2 divs inherit the height of which ever div has higher height inside a parent div?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble matching the height of 2 divs inside a parent div. It's kinda hard for me to explain to I made it on Jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/DSQpd/

Basically, what I wanted to do is match the height regardless of which on is longer. I've already tried putting `height:100%;` on both of em but still doesnt work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the floating and use

```
display: table-cell;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/YzXX7/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally forgot about that!

Comment: `table-cell` will potentially affect the div style in other ways, so this solution should be quarantined from other CSS rules to make it easy to disable should you encounter mysterious issues later on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the most elegant or popular answer, but one extremely straightforward way to do this is to use a `<table>` approach with two cells in a single row. Easy to maintain, works cross-browser, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are ugly. I would also consider using the magic of flexbox for each of your items. The only issue is if you are pulling in dynamic data with Bootstrap or another framework. Then it will make more sense to use the 'clearfix' class every x element or else you will be making more code for yourself. Then again you could always just use JavaScript to determine the highest element and duplicate this across your divs.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

#parent { display: flex; align-items: stretch; }
#child { display: flex;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add margin-bottom:-1000px and padding-bottom:1000px, container div should have overflow:hidden

```
.post {
            width:685px;
            margin:0 0 15px 0;
            float:left;
            background:#EEE;
        overflow:hidden;
        }

            .tags {
                width:250px;
                height:100%;
                padding:0 5px 0 5px;
                float:left;
                background:#273a47;
                color:#FFF;
                padding-bottom: 1000px;
                margin-bottom:-1000px;
            }

            .content {
                width:415px;
                float:right;
                padding:0 5px 0 5px;
                background:#069;
                color:#FFF;

          padding-bottom: 1000px;
                margin-bottom:-1000px;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to implement this with CSS3 is with [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). For your example, adding the following achieves the intended result:

```
.post {
   display: flex;
}
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/DSQpd/11/) with the update above.

Comment: Did you try that on IE ?

Comment: No. I also didn't test on my Nokia phone from 5 years ago or on my CLI browser. This answer is meant to provide a non hack approach, it is not provided as a guaranteed solution for non compliant browsers. The article cited provides vendor prefixed equivalents when available.

Comment: The non hacky answer was already given... And don't bother trying to convince somebody that `display:table-cell` is "hacky" or "mysterious". Or that IE9 and IE19 aren't major browsers. Flex boxes will be interesting in the future but they're just not available now.

Comment: Where is this non-hacky answer? I wouldn't have provided mine if I saw it. Did you intimidate that person to get remove a good answer too? IE9 support should not drive design, especially since IE10 has prefixed support and full support in IE11. I don't know about IE19 yet.

Comment: I intimidate nobody and I don't even ask you to remove your answer, I just precise why it's not, today, the right way to do it if some users are expected to have IE.