# Making a Section Match Another Sections Height with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive site, and I've ran in to predicament on the home page. I have two boxes: a slideshow and a box filled with events. These boxes need to always be the same height, with the slideshow always being the maximum height of the events box. If the events box contains more content than the slideshow, it would just add a scrollbar.

I actually have this working using a bit of jQuery, but I'd really prefer to do it with just CSS. If it doesn't work quite right with IE8 and lower, that's fine.

Here's the script that I want to get rid of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // fixes slideshow and events responsiveness
    function slideshowEventsResponiveness() {
        var figureHeight = $("main > figure").outerHeight();
        var pageMargin = parseInt($(".page").css("marginTop")) + parseInt($(".page").css("marginBottom"));
        $(".page").outerHeight(figureHeight - pageMargin);
        var pageHeaderHeight = $(".page").children("header").outerHeight();
        var pageFooterHeight = $(".page").children("footer").outerHeight();
        $(".scroll").outerHeight(figureHeight - pageHeaderHeight - pageFooterHeight - pageMargin);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        slideshowEventsResponiveness();
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        slideshowEventsResponiveness();
    });
</script>
```

And here's the markup for the home page:

```
<main>
    <figure>
        <section class="bjqs">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/static/sledders.jpg" />
                <figcaption>
                    <h6>Winter Fun!</h6>
                    <p><a href="#">Sledding</a> | <a href="#">Ice Hockey</a> | <a href="#">Ice Skating</a> | <a href="#">Cross Country Ski &amp; SnowShoe Rental</a></p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="images/static/sledders_inverted.jpg" />
                <figcaption>
                    <h6>Winter Fun!</h6>
                    <p><a href="#">Sledding</a> | <a href="#">Ice Hockey</a> | <a href="#">Ice Skating</a> | <a href="#">Cross Country Ski &amp; SnowShoe Rental</a></p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section><!--/.bjqs-->
    </figure>
    <section class="page">
        <header>
            <h1>Latest News &amp; Events</h1>
        </header>
        <section class="scroll">
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1><a href="#"><time>2/10</time> - Ice Skating &amp; Sledding Conditions</a></h1>
                </header>
                <p>
                    Krape Park Sled Hill - OPEN<br />
                    Read Park Ice Rink - OPEN
                </p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1><a href="#"><time>2/1</time> - Registration Now Open</a></h1>
                </header>
                <p>Now taking registration for programs taking place through March 2014. <a href="#">Click here</a> to download a complete copy of the Spring/Summer Program Guide.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1><a href="#"><time>1/28</time> - Winter Activities in Freeport</a></h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin egestas orci ac interdum pharetra.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1><a href="#"><time>1/28</time> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin egestas orci ac interdum pharetra.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1><a href="#"><time>1/28</time> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin egestas orci ac interdum pharetra.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1><a href="#"><time>1/28</time> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin egestas orci ac interdum pharetra.</p>
            </article>
        </section><!--/.scroll-->
        <footer>
            <a class="button" href="#">View All News</a>
        </footer>
    </section><!--/.page-->
</main>
```

If my current CSS would be helpful, I can provide that, just let me know.

Screenshot of my goal:

[image]

UPDATE: Here's a really dumbed-down JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hCHrE/

It's not quite the same markup, but it should work the same.

Comment: Does that answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264634/how-to-make-2-divs-inherit-the-height-of-which-ever-div-has-higher-height-inside

Comment: @dystroy it would take height of the tallest element not slideshow as i see it

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle to let us play with?

Comment: @dystroy unfortunately that doesn't answer it because I need it to take the height of a particular section, not necessarily the tallest.

Comment: @A.Wolff updated the original post.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hCHrE/

Comment: Do you want this ? http://jsfiddle.net/BL6z6/

Comment: @dystroy That's brillant! Was trying same way without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, but it wasn't easy. Some credit goes to @dystroy for giving me the initial idea, but unfortunately his answer only worked in Chrome.

I warn you, this isn't pretty. I utilized a bit of Modernizr to get this working in IE9 (which apparently *kinda* supports flexbox, but not correctly).

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #box {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 960px;
        /* css3 */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }

    .no-flexbox #box {
    }

        #box figure {
            margin: 0;
            width: 40%;
        }

        .no-flexbox #box figure {
            float: left;
        }

            #box figure img {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }

        #box .relative {
            background: blue;
            min-height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            width: 60%;
        }

        .no-flexbox #box .relative {
            bottom: 0;
            float: right;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

            #box .relative section {
                background: red;
                bottom: 0;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                overflow: auto;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <figure>
        <img src="images/01.png" />
    </figure>
    <div class="relative">
        <section>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac diam sapien. Aenean faucibus bibendum dolor eu suscipit. Quisque non eros a diam tristique tempus. Proin fringilla pellentesque ante quis facilisis. Donec gravida velit et ullamcorper tempor. Nulla facilisi. Praesent non quam enim. Nunc ullamcorper, purus sit amet consequat faucibus, nibh enim faucibus nulla, quis facilisis diam nulla id mauris. Sed viverra justo vel risus rhoncus, at ultricies nulla feugiat. Nam in sapien eget diam malesuada feugiat. Fusce imperdiet volutpat ante. Quisque nisl nibh, placerat ac urna eget, scelerisque condimentum ante. Integer semper nisl nec metus lacinia, at venenatis lectus egestas. Mauris vestibulum suscipit nisi, et interdum velit elementum vitae. Morbi ultricies nisl et erat volutpat tincidunt.</p>
            <p>Mauris tempor nibh ut leo pellentesque, elementum pellentesque mauris cursus. Praesent elementum volutpat eros, vitae condimentum nisl laoreet fermentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent eget erat euismod, interdum nibh vel, posuere nunc. Curabitur quis accumsan dolor. Quisque fermentum urna ligula, quis vulputate nunc scelerisque quis. Pellentesque viverra libero sed urna condimentum, ac dictum neque laoreet. Duis blandit, enim pulvinar convallis aliquam, mi sem blandit eros, vel feugiat sem nisi ac justo. Donec imperdiet lectus massa, eu aliquam ante tincidunt lobortis. Phasellus placerat nisl sit amet nibh ornare accumsan. Donec felis tellus, vestibulum in imperdiet eget, facilisis eu libero.</p>
            <p>Vivamus nec mollis lorem. Quisque ullamcorper elit nec mauris blandit, id consequat sapien aliquet. Suspendisse sit amet felis faucibus, viverra enim vel, hendrerit diam. Morbi iaculis, nunc quis tempor ullamcorper, risus tortor luctus mi, vehicula consectetur turpis tortor eu risus. Aliquam purus felis, lacinia eget egestas vitae, volutpat ac massa. Mauris consectetur cursus adipiscing. Curabitur condimentum vulputate ipsum cursus vulputate. Donec urna nisi, lobortis sed mattis in, cursus eget felis. Pellentesque sed sodales mauris. Nam tellus purus, egestas blandit lacus eu, convallis tincidunt neque.</p>
            <p>Etiam sed cursus diam. Curabitur consequat tincidunt libero sed vestibulum. Mauris tempor lobortis dui, in sollicitudin dolor aliquam et. Curabitur rutrum dolor quis urna adipiscing, vel posuere ipsum cursus. Nullam rutrum, erat quis fermentum pellentesque, diam massa placerat risus, quis rhoncus lectus nunc ut felis. Sed hendrerit faucibus diam, at tempor justo gravida ac. Nunc vulputate augue blandit ligula fermentum cursus. Praesent sit amet odio in mi fringilla lobortis vitae sit amet tellus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam semper ligula et nisi tincidunt, vitae egestas enim feugiat. Donec at tristique sem. Praesent tristique, dui eget placerat ultrices, lectus libero dignissim magna, quis condimentum ipsum diam sed magna. Etiam scelerisque ornare eros, nec facilisis erat facilisis nec. Sed volutpat erat in convallis sagittis. Aliquam scelerisque magna leo, vel sagittis mauris mollis non. Aenean bibendum pharetra vehicula.</p>
            <p>Cras facilisis elit ac odio consectetur, id eleifend nunc gravida. Nam faucibus vitae dui at luctus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec lacus enim, tincidunt a nisi nec, venenatis semper nisi. Sed sodales odio id pretium semper. Vivamus quis diam consequat orci elementum dapibus quis vitae neque. Pellentesque sed malesuada mi.</p>
        </section>
    </div><!--/.relative-->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div><!--/#box-->
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9pDv8/

Tested in IE9-11, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Browser on Android, Safari on iOS. Works perfectly in all situations. It degrades in IE8 fairly well, didn't test IE7 at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it

- using `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` to build the two "cells", one being your slideshow and the other one being a container for your text that must take the same height
- wrapping your variable text section in the container and using an absolute position to make it fit the cell

css :

```
#box {
    display:table-row;
}
#a, #box figure {
     display: table-cell;
}
#a { /* #a wraps your section */
    position: relative;
}
#box figure {
    margin: 0;
    width: 30%;
}
#box figure img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#box section {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/BL6z6/)

Comment: This is excellent in Chrome, but unfortunately it's not working in Firefox or IE...Hmm. Maybe I can adapt it somehow. I'll mark this is as the answer if I get it working.

Comment: So far, no luck getting this to work in Firefox and IE. Looks like Firefox doesn't like `display: table-cell;` in conjunction with `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/hCHrE/14/

If i understood your question correctly, all i did was fix the height of the container to the height of the image

```
#box {
background: #EEE;
padding: 25px;
width: 100%;
height:250px;
}
```

Then set the inner containers to match the height of the main container using

```
height:100%;
```

I also used

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

on the content box to get a scroll bar. This makes sure that it will only display a scroll bar if it needs it, not all the time.

The only downside to all of this is that the image must be a static height, so the above answer would probably be better.

Comment: I hope OP wouldn't have asked if the height was static. He could at the very least have simplified the code he uses to compute the height, for example

Comment: Fair comment, I was only trying to help

Comment: Yea, this is a good solution for a static site, but because it's responsive, this unfortunately won't work. I mean, it could if I did the responsive stuff in stages, but I prefer it to flow. Thanks, though.